Error in Subfigure
I want to make 2×3=6, or 2×2=4 subfigure in latex. when I entered the subfigure command correctly, the three figure made successfully, but when entered subfigure command for 4th one this shows an error. And not successfully compiled. So any one can help me, how to solve this issue. Thanks for your response in advance.

Welcome to TeX.SE. Please show us MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document which show what you try so far and what was going wrong at your efforts. With out it is hard to help you.  On site are plenty of cases of figures with such organized subfigures.
